# How to plot degree on spiral chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I have a running Angular 9 application where SVG has a spiral chart with min and max value for the degree.
I am using d3.js to plot given value of degree on the spiral chart.
I have written the following code :

```
// min -> min degree, -140 in this example
// max -> max degree, 440 in this example
// currentDegree -> degree value to be ploted, 0 in this example
// svg -> svg containing spiral chart
// circle -> circle to be moved to depict current Degree position in the svg 

void setDegree(min,max,currentDegree, svg, circle) {

    const pathNode = svg.select('path').node();
    const totalPathLength = pathNode.getTotalLength();

    const yDomain = d3.scale.linear().domain([min, max]).range(
        [0, totalPathLength]); 

    const currentPathLength = yDomain(currentDegree); // current path length
    const pathPoint =  pathNode.getPointAtLength(totalPathLength - currentPathLength);

    circle.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attrTween('cx', () => (t) => pathPoint.x)
        .attrTween('cy', () => (t) => pathPoint.y);
}
```

Above code produces this output :

[image: Click here to see the output :]

In the above image, 0 degrees is slightly shifted to the right but it should have been at the center as shown in the image below :

[image: Click here to see the expected output]

```js
function setDegree(min, max, currentDegree, svg, circle) {
  const pathNode = svg.select("path").node();
  const totalPathLength = pathNode.getTotalLength();

  const yDomain = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([min, max])
    .range([0, totalPathLength]);

  const currentPathLength = yDomain(currentDegree); // current path length
  const pathPoint = pathNode.getPointAtLength(
    totalPathLength - currentPathLength
  );

  circle
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .attrTween("cx", () => t => pathPoint.x)
    .attrTween("cy", () => t => pathPoint.y);
}

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const circle = d3.select("#cur_pos");
setDegree(-140, 410, 0, svg, circle);
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.cls-3 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: #000;
}

.cls-3,
.cls-4,
.cls-5 {
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.cls-4,
.cls-5 {
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
}

.cls-5 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: ArialMT, Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1031.1 1010.3" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <title>Spiral Chart</title>

  <g>
    <g id="Spiral_Chart">
      <g id="Spiral_Path">
        <path
          class="cls-3 svg-range-line"
          d="M881.5,154.9C679.6-47,352.3-47,150.4,154.9c-195.9,195.9-195.9,513.4,0,709.3,189.7,190,497.5,190.1,687.5.4l.4-.4c184.3-184.3,184.3-483,0-667.3h0C659.6,18.1,369.8,18.1,191.1,196.8H191C17.6,370.3,17.6,651.4,191,824.8"
        />
      </g>
      <circle
        id="cur_pos"
        class="cls-4 svg-range-indicator"
        cx="514"
        cy="64.3"
        r="18.5"
      />
    </g>
    <text
      id="Min"
      class="cls-5 svg-text"
      style="text-anchor:start;"
      x="195"
      y="880"
    >
      -140
    </text>
    <text
      id="Max"
      class="cls-5 svg-text"
      style="text-anchor:start;"
      x="885"
      y="210"
    >
      410
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You've made your range equal to the length of the path, which means that if the path is accidentally wrong, then the zero point will also be at the wrong place. Can you please change your code to be a [mre], specifically a runnable snippet? Can be here, or through jsfiddle/codepen/observablehq if you'd like. It'll help you get better answers

Comment: Added running example here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-scb3s9

Answer (score 0):

Because your spiral is smaller on the inside, if you calculate the length at 0 degrees (or 90, or -90), you'll overshoot it. That is because the *total* length of the path includes the outside part of the spiral, which is longer, because it's radius is greater. In other words, your logic is correct if the path would have been completely circular. But it's not so you're off by a little bit.

Note that if you change `currentDegree` to 360, it's almost perfectly placed. That is again because of this radius.

---

I've used this wonderful package [kld-intersections](https://github.com/thelonious/kld-intersections), which can calculate the intersecting points of two SVG shapes.

I first take the midpoint of the circle, then calculate some very long line in the direction I want the circle to have. I calculate the intersections of the path with that line, and I get back an array of intersections.

Now, to know whether to use the closest or the furthest intersection, I sort them by distance to the centre, and check how many times 360 fits between the minimum angle and the desired angle.

**Note** that the centre point is not perfect, that is why if you change it to -140, the circle will not be at the exact end position. Maybe you can improve on this or - if the design is stable, calculate the point by hand.

```js
const {
  ShapeInfo,
  Intersection
} = KldIntersections;

function getCentroid(node) {
  const bbox = node.getBBox();
  return {
    x: bbox.x + bbox.width / 2,
    y: bbox.y + bbox.height / 2,
  };
}

function setDegree(min, max, currentDegree, svg, circle) {
  const pathNode = svg.select("path").node();
  const centroid = getCentroid(pathNode);

  const pathInfo = ShapeInfo.path(pathNode.getAttribute("d"));
  // We need to draw a line from the centroid, at the angle we want the
  // circle to have.
  const currentRadian = (currentDegree / 180) * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2;
  const lineEnd = {
    // HACK: small offset so the line is never completely vertical
    x: centroid.x + 1000 * Math.cos(currentRadian) + Math.random() * 0.01,
    y: centroid.y + 1000 * Math.sin(currentRadian),
  };

  indicatorLine
    .attr("x1", centroid.x)
    .attr("y1", centroid.y)
    .attr("x2", lineEnd.x)
    .attr("y2", lineEnd.y);
  const line = ShapeInfo.line([centroid.x, centroid.y], [lineEnd.x, lineEnd.y]);
  const intersections = Intersection.intersect(pathInfo, line).points;

  // Sort the points based on their distance to the centroid
  intersections.forEach(
    p => p.dist = Math.sqrt((p.x - centroid.x) ** 2 + (p.y - centroid.y) ** 2));
  intersections.sort((a, b) => a.dist - b.dist);

  // See which intersection we need.
  // Iteratively go round the circle until we find the correct one
  let i = 0;
  while (min + 360 * (i + 1) <= currentDegree) {
    i++;
  }

  const pathPoint = intersections[i];

  circle
    .attr("cx", pathPoint.x)
    .attr("cy", pathPoint.y);
}

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const indicatorLine = svg.append("line").attr("stroke", "red");
const circle = d3.select("#cur_pos");

setDegree(-140, 410, 0, svg, circle);
d3.select("input").on("change", function() {
  setDegree(-140, 410, +this.value, svg, circle);
});
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.cls-3 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: #000;
}

.cls-3,
.cls-4,
.cls-5 {
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.cls-4,
.cls-5 {
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
}

.cls-5 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: ArialMT, Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/kld-intersections"></script>

<label>Value</label> <input type="number" value="0" min="-140" max="410"/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1031.1 1010.3" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <g>
    <g id="Spiral_Chart">
      <g id="Spiral_Path">
        <path
          class="cls-3 svg-range-line"
          d="M881.5,154.9C679.6-47,352.3-47,150.4,154.9c-195.9,195.9-195.9,513.4,0,709.3,189.7,190,497.5,190.1,687.5.4l.4-.4c184.3-184.3,184.3-483,0-667.3h0C659.6,18.1,369.8,18.1,191.1,196.8H191C17.6,370.3,17.6,651.4,191,824.8"
        />
      </g>
      <circle
        id="cur_pos"
        class="cls-4 svg-range-indicator"
        cx="514"
        cy="64.3"
        r="18.5"
      />
    </g>
    <text
      id="Min"
      class="cls-5 svg-text"
      style="text-anchor:start;"
      x="195"
      y="880"
    >
      -140
    </text>
    <text
      id="Max"
      class="cls-5 svg-text"
      style="text-anchor:start;"
      x="885"
      y="210"
    >
      410
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can this be achieved without using any 3rd party package like kld-intersections? is there any way to achieve this using just pure d3.js?

Comment: Maybe if you use some binary search algorithm and see if the shapes overlap, but that is tricky. I don't know of a way, I'm afraid

Comment: I tried above solution, it dint work for me, I got zero intersections and thus leading to undefined error. Do you have running example for this? may be on stackblitz or somewhere?

Comment: I've updated the answer to be interactive with a number input. It behaves a little weird around -140, 220, and 410, because the centroid is not correct. You should be able to figure out the correct centroid in the design program you used to create the spiral. Hope that helps